# RSession fatal error when trying to connect do MySQL database via RMariaDB

Tags: mysql, r

Recently my R on Windows 10 breaks down when trying to connect to a MySQL database using RMariaDB. The same error occurs when using RMySQL drivers as well. The error just appeared. The exact same code worked flawlessly about a year ago.

I am using the following code:

```
mydb <- DBI::dbConnect(drv     = RMariaDB::MariaDB(),
                  default.file = "path/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem",
                  username     = "some_username", 
                  password     = "some_password", 
                  host         = "some_host", 
                  port         = 3306)
```

The second I run the dbConnect command, R crashes with the following error:

```
RSession Aborted
R encountered a fatal error.
The session was terminated.
```

My sessionInfo before executing the command is as follows:

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.12.8 RMariaDB_1.0.9   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.3       zeallot_0.1.0    crayon_1.3.4     checkpoint_0.4.7 DBI_1.1.0        backports_1.1.5 
 [7] pillar_1.4.3     rlang_0.4.2      vctrs_0.2.1      tools_3.6.1      bit64_0.9-7      bit_1.1-15.2    
[13] hms_0.5.2        compiler_3.6.1   pkgconfig_2.0.3  tibble_2.1.3
```

My RStudio diagnostics file shows the following issue:

```
17 Jul 2020 22:27:28 [rsession-XXX] ERROR system error 10053 (An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine) [request-uri=/events/get_events]; OCCURRED AT: void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<class rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) c:\jenkins\workspace\ide\windows-v1.2\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:111; LOGGED FROM: void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<class rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) c:\jenkins\workspace\ide\windows-v1.2\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:116
```

So it would seem that there is some issue outside of R, potentially with a firewall or anti-virus software. Consequently, I have added RStudio and all RSessions in the list to the Windows Defender "Allowed Apps" list and tried disabling both Windows Defender and Symantec Endpoint Protection. However, the error keeps occurring. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[default.file](https://rmariadb.r-dbi.org/reference/dbconnect-mariadbdriver-method) is a configuration file, not a certificate.